# styling checkbox and radio button

Tags: css

I have been trying to style checkbox and radio button which are situated inside of td element.The structure follows as:

```
 <table>

      <tr>
        <td>  <input type="checkbox" value="y" title="" id="" editbindings="" groupname="" pt-type="" style=" "> checkbox1</td>
        <td>  <input type="checkbox" value="y" title="" id="" editbindings="" groupname="" pt-type="" style=" "> checkbox1</td>
           <td>  <input type="radio" id="" groupname="" name="gender" checked="" value="" pt-type=""> male
         <td>  <input type="radio" id="" groupname="" name="gender"  value="" pt-type="">  female
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

There are ways to style checkbox and radio button with label. But in my case the code is generated and it is not possible to insert label after input checkbox and radio. I mean html part remains as shown above and it cannot be changed.
I tried the method with  css method. But this works fine only in google chrome. I have attached link to my codepen as well.
http://codepen.io/destinypallavi/details/RGbyoA/
Help from the community is much appreciated

```
-webkit-appearance: none; 
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
```

Any Help from the community is much appreciated, I want styling radio button and checkbox without label technique, making the html intact
Thank you in advance. I dont mind styling with js as well as long as it looks better in firefox and ie10 atleast but if proper technique is available in css3, it would be much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you can't change your html, a pure css solution isn't available. You suggest that javascript is acceptable, so below is a solution using javascript and some modifications to your css:

[Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/TimeSinner/pen/Zpzjja)

The method here is to iterate through your inputs in javascript, add unique IDs, surround the text nodes with a label matching said IDs, and add a class of "styled" (this along with the changes to the CSS means that, should a non-javascript browser encounter this page it will still display correctly according to OS defaults).

I've made a few other necessary changes to your CSS too, however it's a bit messy so you may want to play around with positioning etc.

The important thing, though, is that I've made no changes to the HTML :)

***Disclaimer:*** I'm not very good with javascript so there's probably a better way of implementing this.

### Javascript:

```
var checkboxesToStyle = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");

var radiosToStyle = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]");

var plainLabel = null;
var labelText = null;
var newLabel = null;

for (var i = 0; i < checkboxesToStyle.length; i++) {
    checkboxesToStyle[i].id = "check" + i;
    plainLabel = checkboxesToStyle[i].nextSibling;
    labelText = plainLabel.nodeValue;
    plainLabel.remove();
    newLabel = document.createElement("label");
    newLabel.setAttribute("for", "check" + i);
    newLabel.innerHTML = labelText;
    checkboxesToStyle[i].parentNode.appendChild(newLabel);
    checkboxesToStyle[i].className = 'styled';
}

plainLabel = null;
labelText = null;
newLabel = null;

for (var i = 0; i < radiosToStyle.length; i++) {
    radiosToStyle[i].id = "radio" + i;
    plainLabel = radiosToStyle[i].nextSibling;
    labelText = plainLabel.nodeValue;
    plainLabel.remove();
    newLabel = document.createElement("label");
    newLabel.setAttribute("for", "radio" + i);
    newLabel.innerHTML = labelText;
    radiosToStyle[i].parentNode.appendChild(newLabel);
    radiosToStyle[i].className = 'styled';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice solution:

```
input[type=checkbox].agb {
all: unset;
/* rest of styles here */
}
```

It sets all Browser generated css styles to none and you are able to style the checkbox from scratch like you want to have it without any label hacks or something.

I'll give you an example of a simple custom checkbox of mine.

```
input[type=checkbox].agb {
    all: unset;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: block;
    background: var(--color-2);
    float: left;
}

input[type=checkbox].agb:checked {
    background: var(--color-4);
    color: var(--color-2)
}

input[type=checkbox].agb:checked::after {
    content: "✔";
    display: block;
    font-size: 26px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Should also work with radio buttons.

Comment: This solution works great and for those who are curious it is supported in most major browsers just not IE11 https://caniuse.com/css-unset-value